# A single output request from multiple elements of a JavaRDD in Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, neo4j, streaming, spark-streaming

### Summary

My question is about how Apache Spark Streaming can handle an output operation that takes a long time by either improving parallelization or by combining many writes into a single, larger write. In this case, the write is a cypher request to Neo4J, but it could apply to other data storage.

---

### Environment

I have an Apache Spark Streaming application in Java that writes to 2 datastores: Elasticsearch and Neo4j. Here are the versions:

- Java 8

  Apache Spark 2.11

  Neo4J 3.1.1

  Neo4J Java Bolt Driver 1.1.2

The Elasticsearch output was easy enough as I used the [Elasticsearch-Hadoop for Apache Spark](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html) library.

---

### Our Stream

Our input is a stream from Kafka received on a particular topic, and I deserialize the elements of the stream through a map function to create a `JavaDStream<[OurMessage]> dataStream`. I then do transforms on this message to create a cypher query `String cypherRequest` (using an OurMessage to String transformation) that is sent to a singleton that manages the Bolt Driver connection to Neo4j (I know I should use a connection pool, but maybe that's another question). The cypher query produces a number of nodes and/or edges based on the contents of OurMessage.

The code looks something like the following.

```
dataStream.foreachRDD( rdd -> {
    rdd.foreach( cypherQuery -> {
        BoltDriverSingleton.getInstance().update(cypherQuery);
    });
});
```

---

### Possibilities for Optimization

I have two thoughts about how to improve throughput:

1. I am not sure if Spark Streaming parallelization goes down to the RDD element level. Meaning, the output of RDDs can be parallelized (within `stream.foreachRDD()`, but can each element of the RDD be parallelized (within `rdd.foreach()`). If the latter were the case, would a `reduce` transformation on our `dataStream` increase the ability for Spark to output this data in parallel (each JavaRDD would contain exactly one cypher query)?

   Even with improved parallelization, our performance would further increase if I could implement some sort of Builder that takes each element of the RDD to create a single cypher query that adds the nodes/edges from all elements, instead of one cypher query for each RDD. But, how would I be able to do this without using another kafka instance, which may be overkill?

Am I over thinking this? I've tried to research so much that I might be in too deep.

---

**Aside:** I apologize in advance if any of this is completely wrong. You don't know what you don't know, and I've just started working with Apache Spark and Java 8 w/ lambdas. As Spark users must know by now, either Spark has a steep learning curve due to it's very different paradigm, or I'm an idiot :).

Thanks to anyone who might be able to help; this is my first StackOverflow question in a long time, so please leave feedback and I will be responsive and correct this question as needed.

Comment: We need some info about the Neo4J setup. Do you have any indexes set up? I have been able to knock over elasticsearch pretty easily by firing documents at it since it has to index everything that comes in. Using logstash helps because it will buffer and feed documents to elasticsearch at a speed it can handle. That said, without seeing the type of modifications to the graph that each query is making, we're not going to be able to help much. A complete sample that demonstrated the problem would help. I'm guessing that spark is irrelevant here and a tight loop would show the same issue.

Comment: I object to that mutual exclusivity. Spark has a steep learning curve, *and* I am an idiot.

Comment: @Vidya Fair enough :)

Comment: What is the bottleneck though? Is it neo4j, is it the Singleton, is the building the query? Also, when you say Singleton, what does that mean in a distributed environment, is all of your cypher queries going through the Spark driver, for instance?

Comment: RDD has function `foreachPartition` which gives you an iterator per partition.  You can increase parallelism by doing a repartition, then use `foreachPartition` and a 'thread-local' instance of the BoltDriverSingleton (if that makes sense), to build a mini-batch cypher query. Hope you see what i mean?

Comment: The foreachPartition was something I was considering, but I think it's much simpler than that and I'll post an answer when I get back to my desk in an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all we need is a simple Map/Reduce. The following should allow us to parse each message in the RDD and then write it to the Graph DB all at once.

```
dataStream.map( message -> {
    return (ParseResult) Neo4JMessageParser.parse(message);
}).foreachRDD( rdd -> {
    List<ParseResult> parseResults = rdd.collect();
    String cypherQuery = Neo4JMessageParser.buildQuery(parseResults);
    Neo4JRepository.update(cypherQuery);
    // commit offsets
});
```

By doing this, we should be able to reduce the overhead associated with having to do a write for each incoming message.